# For Next Loop with an If Then inside not working correctly

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a reference image of my worksheet so that everyone can see the format.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d4CY.jpg

The purpose of this is to sort data that matches into columns.  The criteria that I'm looking for is on the right and the database data that i'm looking through is on the left.  Here is my code for the loop.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Counter As Long
Dim WS_Count As Long
Dim k As Long

WS_Count = Worksheets.Count
    For k = 4 To WS_Count
            With Worksheets(k)
                For Counter = 0 To ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -1) - 1
                    For i = 0 To ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
                        If Cells(2 + i, 5).Value = Rows(i + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 1) And _
                            Cells(2 + i, 2).Value = Rows(i + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 3) And _
                            Cells(2 + i, 1).Value = Rows(i + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 2) Then
                              Cells(2 + i, Counter + 7).Value = Cells(2 + i, 4).Value
                        End If
                    Next i
                Next Counter
            End With
     Next k
```

I need to get the Value in column D into columns associated with the criteria on the right.  Columns G:O, numbered 1-9, match the column T numbers, 1-9.

I can't for the life of me figure out why, in Row 4, that it made 0's all the way across.  It should go in this order all the rows in the first column > all the rows in the second column > ... > next sheet.  If anything is unclear please let me know.

Edit: So my `Counter` and `i` Longs were slightly off so I made some adjustments.  They should be right, but my code still isn't executing correctly.  It is not seeing the matches it should.  My `If Then` must be messed up some how.

Comment: since you have `With ActiveSheet` why not use it inside ? `For Counter = 0 To ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -1)` should be `For Counter = 0 To .Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -1)` , and so on... `If Cells(2 + i, 5).Value = Rows(i + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 1)` should be `If .Cells(2 + i, 5).Value = .Rows(i + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 1)` etc. You could avoid using `Worksheets(k).Activate` by using `With Worksheets(k)` instead

Comment: Step through the code. It'll highlight which line is being executed when it is printing 0's. Then you can use the intermediate window to find which values are wrong.

Comment: There that should be a little better.  Laziness mostly.  I had forgot to change it when I added the with.

Comment: I am not sure what result you are hoping to achieve. Let us take two examples, rows 17 and 18. What is the worksheet supposed to look like in these 2 rows after the macro has completed?

Comment: @Vegard  Let's look at Row 17.  Let's say that this is the first time the loop is going through.  Here is what I would like to happen.  If A17=R2 and B17=S2 and E17=Q2 then put the number from D17 into G17.  If the statement does not find a match it goes to the next row down. Column G is only for values that match Q2:S2.  Column H is only for values that match Q3:S3.  Column I is only for values that match Q4:S4.  The final end game is to get the data from Columns A through E Sorted into the and placed into Columns G through O. Hope that helps.

Comment: Alright, so if A18=R2 and B18=S2, you want to put H18=D18?

Comment: @Vegard Not quite.  if A18=R2 and B18=S2 and E18=Q2 then G18=D18

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread the row numbers. Does the code work at all for the other rows? Or does it print nothing in all the rows and 0's in row 4 (ie. the screenshot)?

Comment: It seems that the right-hand in the `IF` comparisons is a likely culprit. I can check in a bit, but if the problem is what I think it is you might have to re-logic the comparison entirely.

Comment: @Vegard Blank entirely except for Row 4 like the screenshot.  http://imgur.com/a/kDY1K Here is an image that will help with how to look at this.  I should have done this right away.  It works the columns from left to right.  I figured that my logic in my statement must be flawed I'll have sit and trace my path for a bit.  Let me know what you can figure out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Counter As Long
Dim WS_Count As Long
Dim k As Long

WS_Count = Worksheets.Count
    For k = 4 To WS_Count
            With Worksheets(k)
                For Counter = 0 To .Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, -1).Value - 1
                    For i = 0 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
                        If .Cells(2 + i, 5).Value = .Rows(Counter + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 1) And _
                            .Cells(2 + i, 2).Value = .Rows(Counter + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 3) And _
                            .Cells(2 + i, 1).Value = .Rows(Counter + 2).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 2) Then
                                  .Cells(2 + i, Counter + 7).Value = .Cells(2 + i, 4).Value
                        End If
                    Next i
                Next Counter
           End With
    Next k
```

Okay, so it works now.  I think it was having a really hard time figuring out what sheet to pull the statements from.  Notice the `.Cells(.....` That period made the Cells defined to the `ActiveSheet`.  I also changed `.Rows(i+2)...` to `.Rows(Counter+2)`  The criteria cell location would shift down with each new `i`making it impossible for there to be a match.  The one in the screenshot just happened to be coincidence.  Thanks, hope this helps someone in the future.